# Ajuda com retorno no SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, select

O `SELECT` abaixo quando rodado diretamente no PHPMyAdmin, retorna todos os resultados que eu quero, porém quando uso na função PHP ele vem vazio:

```
$user = $_SESSION["usuario"]["id"];
$sel = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT lk.*, ep.*
                                    FROM gostados lk
                                    INNER JOIN episodios ep ON 
                                        ep.id_anime = lk.id_anime AND
                                        ep.ep_temporada = lk.ep_temporada AND
                                        ep.episodio = lk.episodio
                                    WHERE 
                                        lk.id_usuario = :user  
                                    ORDER BY data ASC
                                        LIMIT 0,200");

$sel->bindValue(":user", $user);
$sel->execute();
$row = $sel->rowCount();
if($row >= 1){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "0";
}
```

Já conferi o id o usuário que está sendo usado como `bindValue` e está certo, qual poderia ser o erro que faz com que o `$row` sempre retorne 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o seu problema está no inner join,

mude para LEft Join e veja se ele está vindo algo da outra tabela.
Ex:

```
$user = $_SESSION["usuario"]["id"];
$sel = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT lk.*, ep.*
                                    FROM gostados lk
                                    LEFT JOIN episodios ep ON 
                                        ep.id_anime = lk.id_anime AND
                                        ep.ep_temporada = lk.ep_temporada AND
                                        ep.episodio = lk.episodio
                                    WHERE 
                                        lk.id_usuario = :user  
                                    ORDER BY data ASC
                                        LIMIT 0,200");

$sel->bindValue(":user", $user);
$sel->execute();
$row = $sel->rowCount();
if($row >= 1){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "0";
}
```

Explicação:

O inner join vai fazer que só traga registro quando ele achar as associações da outra tabela, caso não tenha algo na tabela episodios que se ligue na linha que você quer ele nao vai trazer, já o left join vai trazer de qualquer forma, desde que tenha na primeira tabela o "gostados"

Comment: Acabei de achar a real raiz do problema aqui enquanto lia seu código, o problema é no ORDER BY data, que na verdade deveria ser lk.data, mas muito obrigado pela dica do LEFT JOIN não sabia que funcionava assim